# Understanding results of df command

Tags: 16.04

what does tmpfs represent below:

```
deploy@ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01:~/server-v2$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              242808       0    242808   0% /dev
tmpfs              50028     624     49404   2% /run
/dev/vda1       20510568 2502884  16951812  13% /
tmpfs             250124       0    250124   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             250124       0    250124   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs              50028       0     50028   0% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 2):

tmpfs is a temporary file system used for quick acces on some files. For more information, look at this: [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) or here: [tmpfs-ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmpfs)